# Problema ao atualizar o dado de um usuário (laravel e jetstream)

Tags: php, laravel, validação

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto como estudo e no momento tenho um problema com uma função.

```
public function alter_cep(Request $request, $product){

        $input = $request->validate([
            'frete' => 'required'
        ]);

        $auth_user = Auth::user();
        $user = User::findOrFail($auth_user->id);
        $user->update([
            "cep" => $request->frete,
        ]);

        $user->save();
        // var_dump($auth_user);
        
        return redirect('/product' . '/' . $product);

    }
```

Quando o usuário clicar em um botão na página de um produto essa função é chamada através da rota e o CEP é atualizado para aquele digitado. Ainda não fiz as validações, mas simplesmente não salva.
Sou redirecionado para a view do produtos, mas o dado "cep" do usuário não é atualizado.

Dando um var_dump no user ele me retorna os campos como "protected", vejam:

```
object(App\Models\User)#844 (32) { ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["table":protected]=> string(5) "users" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["preventsLazyLoading"]=> bool(false) ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["escapeWhenCastingToString":protected]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(15) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(14) "King NES Admin" ["email"]=> string(27) "admin.kingnes2023@gmail.com" ["email_verified_at"]=> NULL ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$BRyrIab5vDIec6SdbO6bT.3faty/NxSvw0/bcQHrlf4VeHmwXOl6S" ["two_factor_secret"]=> NULL ["two_factor_recovery_codes"]=> NULL ["two_factor_confirmed_at"]=> NULL ["remember_token"]=> NULL ["current_team_id"]=> NULL ["profile_photo_path"]=> NULL ["type"]=> int(1) ["cep"]=> NULL ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2023-07-04 10:14:23" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2023-07-04 10:14:23" } ["original":protected]=> array(15) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(14) "King NES Admin" ["email"]=> string(27) "admin.kingnes2023@gmail.com" ["email_verified_at"]=> NULL ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$BRyrIab5vDIec6SdbO6bT.3faty/NxSvw0/bcQHrlf4VeHmwXOl6S" ["two_factor_secret"]=> NULL ["two_factor_recovery_codes"]=> NULL ["two_factor_confirmed_at"]=> NULL ["remember_token"]=> NULL ["current_team_id"]=> NULL ["profile_photo_path"]=> NULL ["type"]=> int(1) ["cep"]=> NULL ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2023-07-04 10:14:23" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2023-07-04 10:14:23" } ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=> array(1) { ["email_verified_at"]=> string(8) "datetime" } ["classCastCache":protected]=> array(0) { } ["attributeCastCache":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "profile_photo_url" } ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["usesUniqueIds"]=> bool(false) ["hidden":protected]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(8) "password" [1]=> string(14) "remember_token" [2]=> string(25) "two_factor_recovery_codes" [3]=> string(17) "two_factor_secret" } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "name" [1]=> string(5) "email" [2]=> string(8) "password" } ["guarded":protected]=> array(0) { } ["rememberTokenName":protected]=> string(14) "remember_token" ["accessToken":protected]=> NULL }
```

Estou fazendo algo de errado? Tem a ver com o "protected"?

Usei o Jetstream para o usuário.

Tentei usar o var_dump e checar os dados enviados, estão todos corretos, sou redirecionado sem erros, mas o dado não é atualizado.

Comment: Em que momento você faz o `$user->save()` para persistir as mudanças no banco?

Comment: No código acima eu não coloquei, mas mesmo colocando ele não funciona. Adicionei antes da linha comentada para testar: $user->save();

Comment: Fiz alguns var_dump aqui:
**string(34) "Antes do update (user->cep): "
 string(34) "Valor do request->frete: 21650-430"
 string(35) "Depois do update (user->cep): "**

O cep é fictício, e o banco aceita o hífen

Mesmo depois de salvar ele fica vazio.

Comment: Você está olhando direto no banco se está salvando?

Comment: Sim, continua vazio no banco. Até porque quando já existe um cep ele chama uma outra função de calcular o frete e o prazo da entrega.

Comment: Acabei de adicionar a linha ' "name" => "TesteNome", ' no update e alterou o nome, só o cep não. Parece ser algum problema nisso, conferi o nome do campo no banco, mas está correto.

Comment: Consegui resolver. No Model "User.php" não tinha adicionado o campo 'cep' na protected $filable. Muito obrogado amigo!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Resolvido! Não havia adicionado o campo "cep" na model User.php.
Antes estava:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
];
```

Então adicionei o cep, ficando:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
    'cep',
];
```

Após isso começou a registrar as alterações!

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).